# Getting Attribute error with Python and Cursor

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor

I am using this posgres , python with cursor. This is my code

```
class User():

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.con = psycopg2.connect(**config)
        self.cursor = self.con.cursor

    def getListS(self):
        from pprint import pprint
        cursor = self.cursor
        cursor.execute("bla bla")
```

I am getting this error

`AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `self.con.cursor` is a method, and should be called in order to get the `cursor` object.

In the `getListS` method do:

```
cursor = self.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * ...")
```